# Store and retrieve native pointer from System::Object^

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, interop

I want to store a pointer to a native class in `System::Object^` and retrieve it back.

```
class ABC;

ABC * d = new ABC();

System::Object^ Tag;
Tag = d; //This throws an error

//in a different function

ABC * c = safe_cast<ABC*>Tag; // this throws an error.
```

Which is the proper way to achieve the above behavior?

Comment: can't you just store the native pointer? why does it have to be an Object?

Comment: Its the Tag property of ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IntPtr structure instead of Object.

```
IntPtr Tag(d);

ABC * c = (ABC*)Tag.ToPointer();
```

Comment: Need to store the pointer in Tag property of ListviewItem. Type is System::Object^

Comment: @Ravikiran : Read up on [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c53ss7ze.aspx).

Comment: @Ravikiran - you can use gcnew InpPtr which is converted to Object^ using boxing.